# Unable to access properties on ComboBox.SelectedItem

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing

Sooo, i keep getting the error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension
>   method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

for the below code- can anyone tell me why?

```
    private void cboDataSets_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int cats = Int16.Parse(cboDataSets.SelectedItem.text);
        lblGenerateSelection.Text = ("you have selected " + (20 - cats) + "cats you'd like to adopt");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cboDataSets.SelectedItem will return an *object*.  If it really contains an object that has a .Text property, you have to cast it

```
int name = 
    Int16.Parse(((SomeObectWithATextProperty)cboDataSets.SelectedItem).Text);
```

If SelectedItem is really a string, you can do this instead:

```
int name = 
    Int16.Parse(((string)cboDataSets.SelectedItem));
```

If SelectedItem is an object that has overridden ToString() to display meaningful data, you can do this

```
int name = 
    Int16.Parse(cboDataSets.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: Glad to help.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please remember to accept an answer that solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

SelectedItem just returns an instance of type object. You need to cast it to the type which actually has the property 'text':

```
((MyType)(cboDataSets.SelectedItem)).text
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear: `cboDataSets.SelectedItem` does not contain a property called `text`, and yet you are referencing that property.

Where did you get that property name from?

`SelectedItem` returns a list item as an object. Type cast as needed to get the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your property is "Text" and not "text" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with big "T", like "Text".